# how to make getRowTotal function in C++ for two-dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays

getRowTotal. This function should accept a two - dimensional array as its first argument and an integer as its second argument. The second argument should be the subscript of a row in the array. The function should return the total of the values in the specified row.

How would one build this function in C++?

This is what I'm working with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

//declare global variables
const int NUM_ROWS = 3;
const int NUM_COLS = 3;

//prototypes
void showArray(int array[][NUM_COLS], int);
int getTotal(int [][NUM_COLS], int, int);
int getAverage(int [][NUM_COLS], int, int);
int getRowTotal(int [][NUM_COLS], int, int);



int main() {

    int total = 0;
    int average = 0;
    int rowTotal = 0;

    int smallArray[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS] = { {1, 2, 3},
                                            {4, 5, 6},
                                            {7, 8, 9} };

    int largeArray[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS] = { {10, 20, 30},
                                            {40, 50, 60},
                                            {70, 80, 90} };
```

Comment: Your code seems to be cut off.

Answer (score 0):

I had modified your prototypes.

```
void showArray( int array[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS] )
{
  for( int i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS; ++i )
  {
    for( int j = 0; j < NUM_COLS; ++j )
      std::cout << (j > 0 ? ',' : '\0') << array[i][j];
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
}

int getTotal( int array[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS] )
{
  int total = 0;

  for( int i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS; ++i )
  for( int j = 0; j < NUM_COLS; ++j )
    total += array[i][j];

  return total;
}

int getAverage( int array[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS] )
{
  return getTotal( array )/(NUM_ROWS * NUM_COLS);
}

int getRowTotal( int array[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS], int row )
{
  int total = 0;

  if( (row >= 0) && (row < NUM_ROWS) )
  {
    for( int j = 0; j < NUM_COLS; ++j )
      total += array[row][j];
  }

  return total;
}
```